# EntityManager com JTA multiplas conexões

Tags: java, java-ee, jpa-2.0, ejb

Estou com um problema meio incomum, mas busco uma solução.

Tenho um cenário onde tenho várias bases de banco de dados(postgresql) alocadas em vários clientes, todas as bases tem a mesma estrutura, mas com registos diferentes.

Tenho uma aplicação em java com `jpa`, `ecliselink` e `ejb 3`, já pronta e em funcionamento, hoje nela eu utilizo o EntityManager deixando o container gerenciar as transações para mim (CMT - Container Managed Transaction), então não preciso ficar dando begin e commit, ele resolve quando executar da melhor maneira.

Bom, tendo isso em mente, preciso continuar a utilizar essa estrutura e não posso mudar para o modo manual (BTM - Bean Managed Transaction), preciso continuar utilizando o CMT (por motivos maiores).
Pesquisando e estudando bastante o conceito consegui realizar a funcionalidade de conectar em várias bases com JTA, só que dessa maneira não consegui que ela seja gerenciada pelo container(CMT), eu teria que dar o begin e commit. Vou postar o código que consegui realizar essa função, se alguém souber como deixar a transação como CMT seguindo essa base de raciocínio eu agradeceria.

O código abaixo funciona, mas não esta executando como CMT, só persiste se ter o begin e commit:

```
@Stateless  
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)  
public class TestEntDAO {  

    private EntityManager em;  
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;  

    @PostConstruct  
    public void init() {  
        em = getEntityManager();  
    }  

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {  
        Map props = new HashMap();  
        props.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.TRANSACTION_TYPE, "JTA");  
        props.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.JTA_DATASOURCE, dataSourceName()); // <- Aqui será injetado o cliente que está logado, pegando a base dele.  
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("testePU", props);  
        em = emf.createEntityManager();  
        return em;  
    }  

    public String dataSourceName(){  
        if(someCondition){  
            return "db1";  
        }else{  
            return "db2";  
        }  
    }  

    public salvar(Tabela tab){  
     em.persist(tab);  
   } //<-- quando termia esse método era para dar o commit automatico (CMT), mais não esta sincronizando as transações.  

}
```

Alguém que entenda bem de JPA poderia me ajudar?

**Observação**: Se alguém falar para usar varios `@PersistenceContext(unitName = "db1")`, não posso usar dessa maneira, por que se caso algum IP sair fora ou der problema em alguma base a aplicação não sobe, dando uma dor de cabeça, também já tentei utilizar o Multitenancy não se encaixou nesse caso.

Comment: O jeito de fazer isso é este mesmo: configurar vários persistence units e identificar qual você deseja usando `@PersistenceContext(unitName = "db1")`. Se você precisa subir teu aplicativo mesmo com um servidor de banco de dados indisponível, talvez fosse melhor pesquisar por este recurso em vez de outra técnica de usar conexões com múltiplos servidores de bancos de dados. Qual servidor de aplicativos você usa? Talvez o próprio servidor de aplicativos disponibilize uma configuração para isso.

Comment: Tentei fazer isso, revirei o glassfish3 de ponta cabeça, se alguma conexão falhar ele lança uma exceção de alocação de conexão. pensando que poderá ter mais de 50 @PersistenceContext criados, imagina a dor de cabeça, fora a manutenção disso, entra e sai cliente. Inviável.

Comment: Hmm lembrei agora que já tive essa necessidade há uns anos atrás (conectar a N databases em N servidores) e terminei com o mesmo código que você postou: sem usar transação gerenciada pelo container. E ainda tive que criar no braço um pool de EntityManagerFactory por questões de performance. Se você encontrar solução melhor, posta aí e me dá um toque por favor. Boa sorte!

Comment: Se eu conseguir eu posto aqui, mais ta bem complicado. Valeu.

Comment: Luciano, na sua implementação o *data source* é definido uma vez na inicialização do *bean*, logo seu DAO acessaria apenas um dos possíveis *data sources*. É assim mesmo que funciona? Ou a aplicação usa diferentes fontes numa mesma execução, dependendo de algum critério? Qual é este critério, isto é, como a aplicação decide qual é o data source?

Answer (score 2):

## JTA, JPA, Data Source?

Acho que você está confundindo JTA, JPA e gerenciamento de conexões (ou EntityManager). Não quero dizer que você não sabe, mas talvez esteja atacando o ponto errado nesta situação em particular.

JTA serve para gerenciar transações distribuídas, onde se altera várias bases de dados ao mesmo tempo. Se isso não ocorre em sua aplicação, não seria necessária usar a API.

JPA lida com a persistência de entidades e lida de forma transparente com a conexão.

Tanto JTA quanto JPA não se preocupam com o *data source* utilizado, exceto é claro em que cada API seja compatível com a fonte de dados, afinal alguns bancos de dados não suportam transações distribuídos ou não são suportados pelo JPA.

## *Multi Tenancy*: diferentes *data sources*

Se entendi bem o seu problema, você precisa usar um *data source* diferente dependendo do cliente logado. Este é exatamente o conceito de **multi-tenância** ou *milti tenancy*.

Uma das formas de se fazer isso usando a API padrão do Java e os *data sources* configurados no *container* é criando um produtor (*producer*) de `EntityManager` para cada requisição.

Usando [a documentação](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkgkv.html), vemos que é possível produzir *beans* em escopos específicos. Se aplicarmos isto ao `EntityManager`, podemos tentar produzir EMs no escopo da requisição:

```
@Produces
@Cliente
@RequestScoped
public EntityManager getClientEntityManager() {
  //TODO produces EntityManager for client
}
```

A lógica do método para produzir o `EntityManager` pode usar alguma variável `ThreadLocal` para definir qual o cliente está logado. Basta criar um `ServletFilter` para anexar à *thread* de cada requisição alguma informação do cliente a partir da qual seja possível determinar o *data source*.

Além disso, é provável que você tenha uma base de dados central com informações de login e dos clientes. Então você pode criar outro produtor para esta fonte:

```
@Produces
@Geral
public EntityManager getGeneralEntityManager() {
  //TODO produces EntityManager for general database
}
```

Os códigos acima associam as anotações customizadas `@Cliente` e `@Geral` com cada *data source*. Portanto, você pode injetá-las independentemente em qualquer classe assim:

```
@Inject @Cliente EntityManager emCliente;
@Inject @Geral EntityManager emGeral;
```

Lembrando que o `EntityManager` específico do cliente só vai estar disponível no contexto de uma requisição

Por fim, apenas para complementar, o método produtor de `EntityManager`s específicos vai precisar criar instâncias do `EntityManagerFactory` sob demanda. Como as *factories* devem ser criadas apenas uma vez, use um mapa global para criá-las na primeira chamada e depois reuse-as a partir do mapa.

## Alguns outros detalhes

- Métodos como `dataSourceName`, `getEntityManager` e `init` deveria ser privados.
- **CMT** não "resolve como executar da melhor maneira", mas coloca transações nos métodos anotados usando a implementação JTA do *container*, então provavelmente sua aplicação usa transações onde não é necessário. Não existe nada mágico que faça o melhor sempre, você precisa ter consciência de quando, que tipo e como demarcar suas transações se quiser desempenho otimizado.

Answer (score 0):

Você deve configurar sua aplicação para utilizar Two-Phase Commit.

Aqui tem dois artigos interessantes:

1. http://java.dzone.com/articles/xa-transactions-2-phase-commit
2. http://blog.endpoint.com/2010/07/distributed-transactions-and-two-phase.html

Espero que ajude ;-)

P.S. Atenção a configuração do `postgresql.conf`, `max_prepared_transactions` tem que ser diferente de zero! Se precisar alterar, tem que reiniciar o serviço.

Comment: A pergunta não tem nenhuma relação com transações distribuídas.